# soap request using sudzc for iphone

Tags: iphone

I found sudzc, this is excellent for generating Documentation Example Source WSDL.

Example, I used this :

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx

sudzc will work for me.

What if I have five webservices? Do I need to generate each of them,
and use it in the application?

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, you will have to use the generator for each operation you want to use.